# How to call fragment from searchview search text in android?

Tags: android, searchview

i want to open a new fragment on text submitting in searchview in android
i have try this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    //*** setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener ***
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {



        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {              
  Toast.makeText(MyDrawerActivity.this, "word is:- "+query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("word", query);
            BlankFragment bm =  new BlankFragment();
            bm.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.replace(R.id.main_container, bm);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchQuery) {


            return true;
        }
    });
```

I have to pass that onQueryTextSubmit(String query) "query" to that fragment page
Thanks

Comment: you are already passing the data?
All you have to do is to access them in your BlankFragment.

Comment: did u find a solution ?